# Python string formatting to get end of a string

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

So I know that I can use either the "%" or ".format" syntax to format string, particularly to trim the end of string to a set number of characters:

```
>>> print("%s" % "12345678990")    
12345678990
>>> print("%.5s" % "12345678990")
12345
```

Is there any way to trim the *beginning* of the string **using string formatting** (not slicing, etc)? The desired output would be:

```
>>> print("%<lst3>" % "12345678990")    
990
```

I have tried the following, to no avail:

"%.-3s"

"%.=3s"

"%.:3s"

"%.:-3s"

And so on.

I have seen nothing in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) about this, but would be happy to be proven wrong! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, I am looking for a way to use string formatting for this, not slicing

Answer (score 0):

well for this problem you have to use `slicing`.

```
print ("12345678990"[8:])
#or
print ("12345678990"[-3:])
```

[Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation) will be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

For strings, taking a slice is more Pythonic:

```
>>> "12345678990"[-3:]
'990'
```

Bear in mind the "wrap-around" behavior of negative numbers in slicing and indexing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
 print("%s" % "12345678990"[-3:])
```